# Lync 2010 Problems - Android 11

Tags: applications, internet, android-11

I have installed Lync 2010 Mobile on my Samsung Galaxy A12 mobile phone.
When I try to connect, it says "the Server Fails a Connection".

I set all required DNS server settings in my Windows Server 2012R2 DNS Server. Set the WIFI DNS to the Windows Server 2012R2. I installed the Mobility Service in the Server 2008 R2 Lync 2010 Server. Still, it will not work.

I **think** I read somewhere that you can change server settings by holding the Home button. Although that opens Google Assistant.

Can anyone please try to help me?

Answer (score 0):

No idea, but maybe you've read to hold the options/multi-tasking button — it's an ancient way to open a context menu that nowadays is found under the three-dots button in UI.

Comment: Well, Lync 2010 Mobile doesn't have that...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).